# Reading from a file in C# without the newline character

Tags: c#, file

i want to read from a text file in C#. But I want all the lines in the file to be concatenated into one line.

for example if i have in the file as

ABCD

EFGH

I need to read ABCDEFGH as one line.

I can do this by reading one line at a time from the file and concatenating that line to a string in a loop. But are there any faster method to do this?

Comment: What's your purpose? Modifying the file on disc or getting the whole content in a variable?

Comment: I have a file with thousands of lines, i want to read them as one line and store that line in a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllLines("path"));
```

Replace " " with "" or any other alternative "line-separator"

**Example file:**

> some line
>
> some other line
>
> and yet another one

*With " " as separator:*
some line some other line and yet another one

*With "" as separator:*
some linesome other lineand yet another one

Comment: Yes i can do this or the replace method, but will that be faster?

Comment: Can you explain why this is more efficient?

Comment: string.Join allocates smartly and has O(n) complexity, where n is the number of lines. string.Replace has O(m) complexity, which m is the number of characters (total) because it goes through each character and compares it to Environment.NewLine, and we know the m > n (the number of total characters is bigger than the number of lines) - so its simply less to loop through.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt")) {
   string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
}
```

Comment: Hi it does not remove the new line characters. for example if i have in the file as
ABCD
EFGH

I need to read ABCDEFGH as one line.

Answer (score 0):

What is a `one line` for you?

If you want to put the entire content of a file into a string, you could do

```
string fileContent  = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\sometext.txt");
```

If you want your string without newline characters you could do

```
fileContent = fileContent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

Comment: This will work, but it is less efficient than using File.ReadAllLines and string.Join

Comment: @Yorye How big is the difference?

Comment: If n is the number of lines, and m is the number of characters in all lines combined, then the difference is multiply by m divide by n. (Since m >= n, it looks promising)

Comment: @Yorye Would you care to explain your reasoning. `string.Replace` just calls some opaque CLR method, so I was not able to compare it with `string.Join` implementation.

Comment: You don't have to look at the disassembly, just think what the logic of the function means. Either put strings end-to-start one after another (resulting with string length x), or go through one long string (with length ~x), comparing each character to a linefeed, and replacing it (maybe even allocating each time a new super-long string - but even if not: tones of unnecessary compares!)

Comment: @Yorye Just for fun, I wrote a quick test(http://pastebin.com/1HiSE1Gi). Turns out that `string.Join` is marginally slower on a test case of 30000 lines of text. Anyway, average difference is 3ms, so it is really irrelevant which one to use.

Comment: I've copied your code, changed lines from 30000 to 1000 and measure loop from 10 to 1000, for accurate yet fast readings, and ran it four times with the following replacements to linefeed: " ", ".", "", "---".

Comment: " ": 2472/2722. ".": 2784/4413. "": 3355/4371. "---": 3404/4380. All won by far with join. (also, I've changed timing from ms to ticks, to avoid small small numbers). Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/XF1p8zUK

Comment: @Yorye I concede :) Producing the requested string via `Join` has one more advantage, it allocates only one gigantic string, instead of two.

Comment: True. I wonder how replace is implemented, though. I expected it to be a lot worse. Maybe it reads until the replacement string, adds to a list, again and again, and then calls join. Otherwise it would allocate tones of strings which would make it slower by whole minutes.

Comment: @Yorye Maybe that's why it is implemented as a CLR method, to overcome said problem via low-level calls.

Comment: I bet, but I think there's something more to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("text.txt").Replace("\r\n", " ");
```